# Alert dialog not being rendered in android, when asking permissions

Tags: android, push-notification, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog, android-permissions

I tried to render a alert dialog when the user don't allow the permission, although the Queue is being filled with the necessary permissions, but the PermissionDialog is not being rendered on the screen. These print statements are also not being logged: println("above alert dialog"), println(dialogQueue) in jetpack compose. Thankyou in Advance for addressing this problem with a solution.

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val permissions = mutableListOf(
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            permissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }
        setContent {
            PermissionsTheme {
                val viewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>()
                val dialogQueue = viewModel.visiblePermissionDialogQueue

                val multiplePermissionResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                    contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(),
                    onResult = { perms ->
                        permissions.forEach { eachPermission ->
                            viewModel.onPermissionResult(
                                permission = eachPermission,
                                isGranted = perms[eachPermission] == true
                            )
                        }
                        println(perms)
                    }
                )

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column(
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        Button(onClick = { multiplePermissionResultLauncher.launch(permissions.toTypedArray()) }) {
                            Text(text = "click")
                        }
                    }
                    println("above alert dialog")
                    println(dialogQueue)

                    dialogQueue
                        .forEach { permission ->
                            println("Queue is being called")
                            PermissionDialog(
                                permissionTextProvider = when (permission) {
                                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION -> {
                                        LocationPermissionTextProvider()
                                    }

                                    android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS -> {
                                        NotificationPermissionTextProvider()
                                    }

                                    else -> return@forEach
                                },
                                isPermanentlyDeclined = !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                    permission
                                ),
                                onDismiss = viewModel::dismissDialog,
                                onOkClick = {
                                    viewModel.dismissDialog()
                                    multiplePermissionResultLauncher.launch(
                                        arrayOf(permission)
                                    )
                                },
                                onGoToAppSettingsClick = ::openAppSettings
                            )
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    fun Activity.openAppSettings() {
    Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
    ).also(::startActivity)
    }
```

Comment: You are only asking for one permission. Why are you using the API for requesting multiple permissions? I wrote an article on asking for location permissions in Jetpack compose. Might be of use for you -> https://proandroiddev.com/location-permissions-done-right-in-jetpack-compose-bb9b3dae8d76.